# JAR to JAR communication

Tags: java, jar, jms

I've been looking for a solution of how to send messages from one JAR to another, I explain:

I have a JAR as a Windows Service, which is running with JSL, let's call it "a files processor", and I have a JavaFX application which has to show the file that is processing the Windows Service.

I've been searching for days now and haven't found a solution. Has anybody ever done something similar?

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: you are talking about JMS. it would be a solution.

Comment: Jar Jar communication? Just change every pronoun to object-case, and add "sa" at the end. "Mesa programmer!"

Comment: what?... I did not understand

Comment: @user3511962 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jmF900DHKk

Comment: lol...now I understand :D...nice one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use ActiveMQ, It´s really easy.
I´m going to have a sender and a listener, both in different applications
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

There's a load of ways to have two processes talk to each other - the most common two, that are standard in Java, are [Remote Method Invocation API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) (RMI) and [Java Message Service API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdr.html) (JMS).

For synchronous calls that allow one process to invoke a method on an object in another process, the Java standard is [Remote Method Invocation API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) (RMI).

For asynchronous message passing, the Java standard is the [Java Message Service API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdr.html) (JMS).

The simple way to decide between these two technologies, is to ask whether the UI will simply poll the service to obtain updates or if requires updates pushed to it by the service - if it's the former (polling) use RMI, if it's the later (updates pushed) then use JMS.

My preference, while it's more work would be the JMS route because it gives a slicker experience in the UI but it is however more work to implement so there's a trade-off.

Comment: What about ActiveMQ, would you use It?

Comment: You use JMS to connect to ActiveMQ

Comment: That is correct...I´ll check It up and let you know...Thanks